# How to limit client to have collection to 1?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I created collection "Users" and I can make CRUD operation, but now I want to make a limit to user to have ability to create one collection, and when it have one, can just update the date.

```js
const URC = collection(db, "Users");
const submitFun = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  (async () => {
    const { name, desc, email, adres, website, phone, photo } =
      formData.current;

    await addDoc(URC, {
      name: name.value,
      desc: desc.value,
      email: email.value,
      adres: adres.value,
      website: website.value,
      phone: phone.value,
      photo: photo.value,
    });
  })();
};
```

Do I have to in this function make an if statement?
How to give user.id to this function to work it proper?

Comment: probably, you can add a created_by field on your collections, so whenever a user enter the application it query if there's any collection created by this user, if true, just use it

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in that can help you limit the user to create only one collection. However, that can be solved really simply. You can create a document that can hold an array of UIDs. When a user creates a collection, add the corresponding UID to that array. Each time a user needs to perform such an operation, check that array against the UID. If it is not present, let the user create the collection, otherwise, don't allow it.

The schema may look like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- restrictions (collection)
         |
         --- data (document)
              |
              --- uids: ["uid", "uid"]
```

This can be much easier in the Realtime Database, where a possible schema should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- restrictions
         |
         --- uid: true
```

In this way, you should only check if a particular UID exists under `restrictions` node.

Comment: I tried to make rule for that statement but something not work properly ```     match /Users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
          } ```
and of corse I add object to array ```  uid:  user?.uid, ```

Comment: Without seeing the code that does that and all the rules, I cannot be much of a help. But for that, I recommend you post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information here?

Comment: I can put as much information as you need; I created another post, because you asked me for it.

Comment: But do not add similar questions, as they can be marked as duplicates.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: I misunderstand you, I guess you want me to add userID to an object, where I put date, and then map all document to search with userId. 
2. I created in collection Users, document "UserID" but I do not know how to access to it, because I get an error "collection can have just 1 copies"  ```   const URM = collection(db, "Users", "UserID");

Comment: No.  Please check my updated answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Hey, Kamil. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thx for asking. At now everything works fine. I used frank's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73320027/how-to-set-rules-to-users-in-firebase solutions because was easier for me. Once again, thx for support.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in perspective where email id is unique for users.
One approach , you will have document ids unique. You can get document by email.

```
    const q = query(collection(db, "Users"), where("email", "==", "abc@yourdomain.com"));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    if(querySnapshot && querySnapshot.length == 0){
     await addDoc(URC, {
          name: name.value,
          desc: desc.value,
          email: email.value,
          adres: adres.value,
          website: website.value,
          phone: phone.value,
          photo: photo.value,
        });
    }else{
  //This will update existing document.
     doc = querySnapshot[0]
     await setDoc(doc,{
          name: name.value,
          desc: desc.value,
          email: email.value,
          adres: adres.value,
          website: website.value,
          phone: phone.value,
          photo: photo.value,
        });
    }
```

You can find more information on [setDoc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) and [query()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).

Another approach having email as document id. But it is not recommended. Because if application allows email id change , document id should also be changed. And it is better to handle unique objects by id.

Comment: I've change a little because instead of email, I used ``` user?.uid ``` which I can get from ``` useAuthState(auth); ``` and I add as one of require field. 
But the problem is different, whatever I add as else statement I get an error:  ``` TypeError: t is not an Object. (evaluating '"_delegate" in t') ```