# How to set rules to users in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to create new rules for my client - one client can create one document in collection.

```
         match /Users/{userId} {
      allow update, delete: if request.resource.data.uid == uid;
      allow create: if 
       request.data.uid != request.resource.data.uid;
```

if request uid ==  request.resource.data.uid; he cannot.

Comment: What's wrong with these rules?

Comment: What is `uid` here ? in `allow update, delete: if request.resource.data.uid == uid;` maybe you meant `userId`

Comment: @AlexMamo One user can create as many document as he wants; but I want to make a limit to just one (and if so, he can only update, delete)

Comment: That's almost the same question as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73310282/how-to-limit-client-to-have-collection-to-1). So try to create the mechanism in my answer and then write the proper rules.

Answer (score 2):

If you want each user to only be able to create a single document, that is easiest if you use the user's UID as the document ID. In JavaScript that'd be something like this:

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const user = getAuth().currentUser;

await setDoc(doc(db, "Users", user.uid), {
  displayName: user.displayName,
});
```

You can then enforce this [content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access) in security rules with:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /Users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```

The main difference with your approach is that we don't check the **data** of the document, but instead check the document ID (which we set to the UID in our code) to the UID on the request.